# When $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n] \to K[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m]$ is a flat morphism

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

Let $K$ be a field and $\varphi: K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n] \to K[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m]$ a polynomial $K$-algebra morphism. Assume $n, m \ge 2$. By definition $\varphi$ endows $K[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m]$ with a $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$-module structure.

Are there any available criteria to decide when the $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$-module $K[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m]$ induced in this way by $\varphi$ a *flat* $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$-module?

I want also to note that this generalizes [this MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667095/polynomial-map-kt-to-kt-induces-flat-module-structure).

As far as we consider the case with more than one indeterminantes. The case $n=m=1$ always has a positive answer since $K[X]$ is a PID and in this setting flat = torsion-free. For $n \ge 2$ $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ is not a PID, so the criterion is not applicable.

An approach is to use a lemma that states that if $R \to R', S \to S'$ are flat modules, then $R \otimes S \to R' \otimes S'$ is a flat $R \otimes S$-module. The point is that obviously not every polynomial map $\varphi: K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n] \to K[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m]$ arises from such "atomic" pieces $\varphi_i: K[X_i] \to K[Y_i]$ as tensor product $\bigotimes_i \varphi_i$.

So I'm asking if there exist approaches dealing with this problem or is it too broad?

Comment: The geometric way to look at it is that $\phi \colon \mathbf A^m \to \mathbf A^n$ is flat if and only if all fibres have dimension $m-n$. This follows from "miracle flatness"; see e.g. Tag [00R4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00R4).

Comment: I suspect you mean "$K$-algebra homomorphism" rather than just "ring homomorphism".

Comment: @YCor: Yes, thanks.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!